# Want to call windows applications from vim under cygwin

Tags: windows, bash, vim, cygwin

I have vim and mintty installed with cygwin.
Have some aliases in bash profile, they work in terminal.
Then I call :!bash from vim, I have the same mintty terminal, but have to source .bash_profile again. 
My original intent was to call command `:!chrome %`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to save some overhead, the default shell used by Vim to invoke external commands (i.e. via `:! {cmd}`) is a **non-interactive** one; it doesn't read the usual initialization files.

If you want to use shell aliases, you can reconfigure Vim to start an interactive one (adding the `i` flag):

```
:set shellcmdflag=-ic
```

Aliases are typically defined in `.bashrc`; however, you mention `.bash_profile`. That one is only read for *login shells*, so either move the alias definitions, or start an (even slower) login shell by supplying the `l` flag in addition to `i`.

Comment: That works. Thanks!

Comment: I have to call "fg" and hit Enter to get back into vim now. Can I get around that? Adding "&" to command helps, I only hit enter then.... Binding the comand to a key and trailing it with <CR> helped!